# Baggage Transfer through Turkish Airlines

Tags: luggage, airport-transfer, yyz

I have a flight from YYZ to IST, where I will be staying for a few days until I fly to LHE. I am travelling with children and have bags with me that I wont need until I reach LHE. It is a single ticket. Is there anyway that I can have them sent straight from YYZ to LHE? I can arrange for pickup from the airport in LHE.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The airline will not be able to store your luggage for such a long connection, and your bags are not legally allow travel on a different flight to you (there are exceptions, but they will not be relevant here).

You will need to collect your bags on arrival in Istanbul, and then re-check them with the airline shortly before departure.

If you do not wish to carry your bags to/from your hotel, there is a service called [Miniport](https://miniport.istanbul/en) that can do this for you relatively cheaply (as low as a few dollars per bag, depending on the destination).

According to the [Turkish Airlines website](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-tr/istanbul-airport/faq/index.html) regarding the new Istanbul airport, "*There are left luggage/baggage check areas at two different locations at the passenger terminal arrivals level. There are electronic baggage boxes located in the passenger terminal departures level*", however there is no mention of price, and as the new Istanbul airport has only recently opened there don't seem to be any reports of prices on the internet that I can find.